# Is a maximum of fifty links in my situation desirable, or every high-quality work I want to include?

Tags: seo, links, pagerank

I have an old domain A.com which has PageRank 4 and newer domain B.com which has PageRank 2. I have been redirecting from A.com to B.com.

Now I am in the process of adding a non-redirected homepage to A that includes deep links to major works on the site B. I've heard that Google penalizes pages for having more than 50 links.

Under the circumstances (300 or so total links available), do I want to make all links transfer, or only a slimmed-down list of 49?

Thanks,

Comment: Where did you hear about this 50 link limit?   Google used to recommend no more than 100 links per page, but they removed that recommendation years ago.  I've never heard of a penalty for too many links (as opposed to a penalty for low quality or spammy links.)  See [How many links (internal) is too many?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/how-many-links-internal-is-too-many)

Comment: Why are you creating this home page on an otherwise redirecting domain anyway?

Comment: To direct traffic from the old domain to the new domain. The site has moved.

Comment: Isn't that what a redirect would be for? why not just redirect the homepage of the old site to the homepage of the new site? That's what most website moves do.

Comment: PageRank, from the sources I had checked, has not been transferred when I redirect the homepage. I thought that zero PageRank transferred from a redirect would be less desirable than links from a PR4 page to the new location.

Comment: How are you checking PageRank?   Google still uses it internally but doesn't make the data public.  Google retired the Google toolbar and the Google directory.  There is now no way to know what Google has determined the PageRank to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be working under some misconceptions.

The fist one I want to address is the notion of PageRank of a domain. Google has not made these metrics available in quite a few years. If you are getting this metric off of a website, please ignore it. It is garbage.

The second is that creating a page with links from one domain to another will boost search performance. If there are no links to the old domain or links of little value, any link you create will have little or no value.

Additionally, you do not want to appear to be making links in an unnatural manner.

The old notion of a PR 6 site with 2 links passing PR 3 for each link has always been incorrect. This is not how PageRank works. Without getting into details, if you expect to pass value from the old domain to the new domain, you will be disappointed. More or less links do not help.

Google will not reward a single link from a home page where there is no site. This could be seen as spam. Google sees an empty site as having no value.

What you should do is build links from other high quality and on-topic sites to your new domain. Just one high value link does wonders. A few moderate value links does more for your site than you can imagine. Make sure that these links are made in a natural way, that is, in a way that any webmaster would create a link.

There is no substitute for real work. Google appreciates and rewards it.